# Differences of R console vs. R script environment; error with installed.packages()

Tags: r, cran

I am new to R, and I've spent a while getting ramped up on example scripts on the web, I came across a script that had a bunch of `require(<package>)` lines. Rather than writing `install.packages(<package>)`, I modified the script as such:

```
package_names <- c('caret',
              'readr',
              'xgboost',
              'ggplot2',
              'R.utils',
              'gridExtra',
              'lubridate',
              'data.table',
              'Matrix',
              'plyr',
              'Hmisc',
              'maps',
              'maptools',
              'sp',
              'corrplot')
for (package_name in package_names){
  if (!package_name %in% rownames(installed.packages()))
      install.packages(package_name)

    eval(parse(text=sprintf("require(%s)",package_name)))
}
```

So that it would attempt to install the package if it wasn't installed, before requiring it. However executing this **as a script** in R studio resulting in the following error:

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url
```

I am not explicitly calling `contrib.url` so I didn't really know where to begin.

But then I tried copying and pasting those exact lines and running them in a **command line R Studio interpreter** session (repl), and voila, it ran and installed/updated all those packages flawlessly.

This brings me to the question: What's the difference between the command line session and the script that caused this error?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: I believe **pacman** package's `p_load` function would take care of all of this for you including the cran repo set.  It would make the code more succinct and readable.

Comment: Incidentally, the code can be made into more idiomatic R code in two lines, by using `install.packages(setdiff(package_names, rownames(installed.packages())))` instead of the loop. To call `require` (better: `library` — no need for `require`!) with a variable, use `require(var, character.only = TRUE)`. You can do this for all packages at once using `invisible(Map(library, package_names, character.only = TRUE))`. Two statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the CRAN mirror in your script, from amongst the options returned by `getCRANmirror()`, e.g.,

```
chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
```

As suggested by @KonradRudolph, a more idiomatic way might be to install any missing requirements and then to `require()` all packages.

```
chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
needed = package_names[!package_names %in% rownames(installed.packages())]
install.packages(needed)
ok = sapply(package_names, require, character.only=TRUE)
if (!all(ok)) {
    bad = paste(package_names[!ok], collapse=", ")
    stop("failed to 'require' packages: ", bad)
}
```